# Not allowed to load local resource: chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that replaces the new tab with a video. A common request I get from users is to be able to get back to their home screen, which is accessible here when you type this into the browser

`chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html`

I added a home button that takes the user to the url above, but when I click on the button I get an error in the console:

`Not allowed to load local resource: chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html`

Has anyone come across this before or have some guidance on how to get around this issue?

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.update as shown in the linked topic.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this. It loads the page I am looking for onClick, but I am getting an error in the console still:

local-ntp.js:2088 GET chrome-search://local-ntp/search-suggestions.js net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Probably a bug in Chrome. See if it's reported on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Cool, thanks for that link. I'll mark as resolved because it seems to be working locally. Hopefully, when I publish it will work fine too.